# Developing a web app with ZK, IntelliJ and Maven

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, zk

I would like to create a web app with the ZK framework with Maven and the IntelliJ IDE. 
I can't find any tutorial that can help me on this. Do you have any tips?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add zk as maven dependency.
 Then go to [zk home page and read documentation](http://zkoss.org).
But i guess using [Zk-Studio](http://www.zkoss.org/product/zkstudio), means use eclipse, is a better idea.